# jQuery jail plugin makes firefox extremely slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have images on page which are loaded if user scrolls down to them and this functionality is made by using jQuery plugin named [JAIL](https://github.com/sebarmeli/JAIL). 
Everything works fine and fast in chrome, but firefox lags very much (sometimes it takes a few seconds to scroll down a bit).

Images are "jailed" in this way:

```
$("img.lazy").jail();
```

Did somebody face the same issue?

Comment: have you read the issues in that git? https://github.com/sebarmeli/JAIL/issues/41 for example

Comment: @JaromandaX it does not give any solution beside the one, that suggests not to use jail if it IE (in our case it is ff)

Comment: I haven't read all of the issues, just asking if you had

Answer (score 0):

As long as last time the library was updated a year ago I changed it to [another](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload). It didn't take much time and performance is much better in FF and slightly seen in Chrome.